# ng-show not binding as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have a simple 'toggle' on my form. If I click one button, then I should activate a correspondingly-named section, otherwise it should be hidden from view. My issue appears to be that of a scope one. If I don't use an isolated scope on my substeps, then both substeps will appear active on one toggle and inactive on the other (this is incorrect behaviour). If I *do* use an isolated scope, then `isActive()` is never called.

My code is as follows.

```
<div ng-controller='SubstepCtrl'>
    <button activates='CreateNewMeter'>
        Create new Meter
    </button>

    <button activates='UseExistingMeter'>
        Use Existing Meter
    </button>

    <div class='sub-step' substep='CreateNewMeter' ng-show='isActive(name)'>
        <h1>Create New Meter</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='sub-step' substep='UseExistingMeter' ng-show='isActive(name)'>
        <h1>Use Existing Meter</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
.controller('SubstepCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.activeSubstepName = undefined;
    $scope.isActive = function(name) {
        return $scope.activeSubstepName == name;
    };
})

.directive('activates', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.on('click', function() {
                $scope.activeSubstepName = $attrs.activates;
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
})

.directive('substep', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.name = $attrs.substep;
        }
    };
});
```

I have managed to achieve this in a fairly hacky way with JQuery but I was wondering if there was a way to Angular-ify it.

The expected behaviour is that if I click the "Create new Meter" button, that the "CreateNewMeter" substep should be displayed, and the "UseExistingMeter" should not. As I understand the issue here is that the substep divs are not creating a subscope and are both using the parent scope - therefore name is undefined - right?

If so, how can I remedy this?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I skipped over that. However it is $scope.activeSubstepName in the actual code.

Comment: Your substep directive sets `$scope.name` in your controller to the name of the last substep element on the page which is why you see them both showing up (they both use the same "flag")

Comment: You need to pass name properly.. http://plnkr.co/edit/2KowNF?p=preview You'r substep just uses the controller scope, so `name` property on the scope will be overwritten by the last instance of the directive.

Comment: The idea was that the substep directive has a name, which would have been used as the attribute. I guess this works though :(

Comment: @DanPantry you have a dir just for that, in which case you would have to use 2-way binding.. But why you need it at all, you could just have name for both the components in the controller itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in which you create a new directive with it's own isolated scope.  In my opinion, this is a better solution, especially since it allows you to have as many sub-steps as you want.

What you need to do when you create your isolate scope in the directive is have a property for both the `name` and for the `isActive` function.  Since the `name` is just a string that you have defined in your html, you can specify it as an `@` attribute so that is set in your directives scope to the string you specify in your html.  I created the function (passing it to the directive using the `&` syntax) to be called `showWhen` and if you notice, in order to pass in the parameter `name` that you specify in your function in the html,  you need to pass an object *within* your directive that uses `name` as a key with the directives `name` as the value.

The html:

```
<div ng-controller='SubstepCtrl'>
    <button activates='CreateNewMeter'>
        Create new Meter
    </button>

    <button activates='UseExistingMeter'>
        Use Existing Meter
    </button>

    <button activates='UseImaginaryMeter'>
        Use Imaginary Meter
    </button>

    <button activates='none'>
        "Clear" all
    </button>

    <substep name="CreateNewMeter" show-when="isActive(name)">
      <h1>Create New Meter</h1>
    </substep>

    <substep name="UseExistingMeter" show-when="isActive(name)">
      <h1>Use Existing Meter</h1>
    </substep>

    <substep name="UseImaginaryMeter" show-when="isActive(name)">
      <h1>Use Imaginary Meter</h1>
    </substep>
</div>
```

The directive code:

```
.directive('substep', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        name: '@',
        showWhen: '&'
      },
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div ng-transclude class="sub-step" ng-show="showWhen({name:name})"></div>'
    };
});
```

Here is a sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TKJehABKIPPHRbrUrqr3?p=preview

Comment: Could you explain what `&` does? :) I know I could google it, but I figure for sake of completeness in case someone else stumbles across this question.

Comment: You use `&` in the isolate scope definition object when you want to pass a pointer to the directive to be able to call a function from your controller scope. See the [directive scope documention](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) for more information

Comment: Marking this one as accepted as it is not constrained by having just 2 options. If that's a faux pais I apologise :(

Comment: Don't worry, it's best/recommended to accept the best answer.  See [this related question on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267551/does-the-answerer-lose-award-points-when-i-first-accepted-his-answer-and-then-ch?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which avoids creating your own directive:

```
<div ng-controller='SubstepCtrl'>
    <button ng-click='setMeter("new")'>
        Create new Meter
    </button>

    <button activates='setMeter("existing")'>
        Use Existing Meter
    </button>

    <div class='sub-step' substep='CreateNewMeter' ng-show='meter === "new"'>
        <h1>Create New Meter</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='sub-step' substep='UseExistingMeter' ng-show='meter === "existing"'>
        <h1>Use Existing Meter</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

set a function on your controllers' scope:

```
.controller('SubstepCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.activeSubstepName = undefined;
    $scope.isActive = function(name) {
        return $scope.activeSubstepName == name;
    };
    $scope.meter = null;
    $scope.setMeter = function(meterType) {
        $scope.meter = meterType;
    };
});
```

Comment: This is a decent solution however it breaks if I have more than one substep. That said my question does only allow for two sub-steps, so I suppose it'll do :p