# What is the correct way to wrap Angularjs code in a closure?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I have a simple application outlined in this question: [Angular scope not affecting ng-show as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745646/angular-scope-not-affecting-ng-show-as-expected)

Which exposes my application via global variables, this is obviously not ideal.

I have tried wrapping the Angularjs code in a closure but I get errors in the browser telling me that the objects I am trying to access aren't accessable.

```
(function() {

// App code here

});
```

Is there a way to expose my app so with the current layout it functions correctly or do I need to change the whole struction of my app to achieve this.

I am ideally trying to reduce global variable pollution while keeping the app structure the same in both the html and js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the call part.

Here is one format, there are a few others.

```
(function (a, b){
    //Do stuff with `a` and `b`
})("a", "b");
```

Note the final pair of parens.  Any parameter that you define, and later pass in are global within the scope.

Comment: Wow what a mistake... Thanks for the speedy reply